# How to set options of each cluster in MarkerClusterGroup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I create my own MarkerClusterGroup with the following way:

```
this.cluster = leaflet.markerClusterGroup({
    zoomToBoundsOnClick: false,
    showCoverageOnHover: false,
    spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 3,
    spiderLegPolylineOptions: {
        weight: 1.5,
        color: "#1BA5D0",
        lineCap: "butt",
        dashArray: "10 10",
        opacity: 0.5
    }
});
```

How can I apply some options for each cluster (as far as it actually leaflet.Marker) inside that group? Especially, I would like to set `riseOnHover: true`

I found out that there is [some way](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/example/marker-clustering-pane.html) with controlling whole MarkerClusterGroup positioning with custom panes but this is not my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. Options could be set inside `iconCreateFunction`:

```
this.cluster = leaflet.markerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: cluster => {
        cluster.options.riseOnHover = true;
    }
});
```